# How to provide search input with python selenium liberary?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

from the following website, I want to provide a search input "3M" in "Type organization's name" box and then hit on 'Go' button.

I was able to open the website using the following script in python however required help on searching part.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

url = "http://database.globalreporting.org/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [attribute=value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selector to target the input box and an id to target the go button. You might consider adding expected conditions and wait but seems to run fine without.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://database.globalreporting.org/'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=q]').send_keys('3M')
d.find_element_by_id('home-search-text').click()
# other code
#d.quit()
```